# Equivalent Planes?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The three planes $x=y$, $y=z$, $x=z$ cut the unit cube $0\le x\le1$, $0\le y\le1$, $0\le z\le1$ into $n$ pieces. Find $n$.

My question is this: what does $x=y$, $y=z$, $x=z$ mean? If all of the planes are equal, doesn't that just cut the cube into 2 pieces, or 1 piece if the plane is on a face of the unit cube? I don't get how equivalent planes work. Also, how do you solve for $n$?

Comment: The plane $x=y$ represents $(x,x,z)$.  To think about this, think of a line with slope one in the $x-y$ plane (ie $y=x$).  Now, adding on the $z$ component gives you the plane that is obtained by shifting that line up or down the $z$ axis.  Similarly, for $y=z$, we have a plane of the form $(x,y,y)$.  Now, we have a line in the $y-z$ plane.  A similar construction can be made.  Intuitively, you have a cube and you are cutting it diagonally three times along the different planes (that is, the $xy$ plane, $yz$ plane, and  $xz$ plane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the nearest book/cubic object next to you and choose directions for the $x,y,$ and $z$ axes (hopefully parallel to the edges of the book).  Now, let's look at what the $x=y$ plane does.  Forget about the $z$ axis.  $x=y$, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, represents a straight line with slope $1$.  So, if we let the $x-y$ axes be the "bottom" of the book, this plane will be the set of points of the form $(x,x,z)$.  In other words, if you draw a line along the bottom of the book with slope $1$, just think of the plane as the set of points generated by the translation of the line $x=y$ directly up or down.  We can do similar constructions for the other two planes.

So, once you get the intuition down for the planes, solving for $n$ becomes relatively easy.  The first plane cuts our cube into $2$ distinct pieces.  The second plane cuts these each of these pieces into $2$ more distinct pieces.  The last plane is a bit special since it will miss two out of these four pieces generated by our first two cuts.  In particular, the last plane will only cut two pieces so that $\boxed{n=6}$.

An extension to this problem is: what is the maximum number of pieces that can be created by $m$ planes?  This is known as the cake number:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number
$$\frac{n^3 +5n + 6}{6}$$
Try to realize a few of these bounds in the simpler cases.

Answer (score 0):

An equation $f=g$ can be a shorthand for **the set of solutions to** $f=g$.

So for example "the plane $x=y$" really means the plane $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x=y\}$. This includes, for example, the points $(1,1,0)$ and $(5,5,-2)$, but not the point $(0,1,3)$.